# How to hide or disable the progress popups in SharePoint list?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

Is there any way to disable or hide the progress popups within SharePoint list. These popups are interfering with the my custom form.

[Progress PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmG7g.jpg)

According to MS Community, it seems there is no option to solve this issue. So thought of seeking some additional advise.

Comment: As per my knowledge, I'm afraid it is not supported to hide the popups either OOTB or custom solution. You can provide feedback to MS here: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472. MS would take this into consideration if it si highly voted.

Comment: Noted. So will upvote for this option. Really appreciate your time and support.